# ListView.builder's index doesn't reset when calling setState. Found a weird fix for it. Is there a better solution? Why is this happening?

Tags: flutter, listview, debugging, indexing, setstate

I have this listview.builder which is supposed to show some orders from an array of Order objects based on their status.
It looks kinda like this:

[image]

The List works just fine until, for some reason, when I scroll down and the viewport can only display the order with index (the one in the listview builder function) 5 and then press another category like "New", setState() is called and the whole thing rebuilds, but the builder's index starts at 5 and the listview.builder doesn't build anything from 0 - 4. I've printed the index in the builder and caught this bug, but I still don't understand why this is happening.

This is what my listview.builder code looks like:

```
ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print("INDEX: $index");

              return _showOrder(index);
            },
            itemCount: orders.length,
          ),
```

This is the code for _showOrder():

```
Widget _showOrder(int i) {
    String _currOrderStatus = orders[i].orderStatus;

    /// _selectedOrderStatus is just a String which changes depending on the selected category of orders.
    /// e.g. "New" or "Past"
    return _currOrderStatus == _selectedOrderStatus
        ? ShowMyOrderWidget()
        : SizedBox(

            /// AND FOR SOME REALLY WEIRD REASON, THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM
            /// It works with any height, as long as it's not 0, but if I have a lot of them, then the 
            /// layout gets spaced out and messy. With such a low number, this is highly unlikely, but 
            /// still seems like a stupid fix.
            /// Why does this work? Why is this happening? Is there a better way to fix it?
            height: 0.000000001,
          );
  }
```

And I just call `setState()` in the `onPressed()` function of those buttons on top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the items inside the ListView doesn't reset scroll position.
Since you're already assigning a ScrollController to your ListView, try calling "jumpTo(0.0)" to reset it's scroll position before calling setState().

```dart
_scrollController.jumpTo(0.0);
```